# R data.table column that counts along unique values in other column

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr

I have some data in long format that I want to make wide.
The issue is that the data is in a format doesn't have one piece of information that makes spreading easy. To get around this, I have to create a column in the data frame that counts from 1 to the length of each unique entry in another column.

In the process below, is there a data.table way of making the column "fid"?

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

# data:
df <- data.frame(class = c('1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '3'),
                 A = 1:6,
                 B = 11:16)

# create counting column
df <- df %>% group_by(class) %>% mutate(fid=1:n())

# spread using dcast
dcast(setDT(df), class ~ fid, value.var = c("A", "B"))
```

Cheers

Comment: Yes, `rowid`. use `class ~ rowid(class)`  in `dcast`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is using `data.table::rowid`.

```
df[,fid := rowid(class)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The data.table way of creating the column 'fid', is to convert the `data.frame` into `data.table` (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'class', get the sequence of rows (`seq_len(.N)`) and assign (`:=`) it to 'fid'

```
setDT(df)[, fid := seq_len(.N), class]
```

However, creating a column is not at all needed if the intention is to use `dcast` as there is a `rowid` function which can directly be used in the formula as @mt1022 suggested